# Get DOCUMENT from another DOCUMENT with JSExecutor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get an element from a page and click on it. But I came across the #document tag.
My last step with this problem:

```
var doc = (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)_driver.ExecuteQuery("return window.document");
doc.FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='Принять']").Click();
```

But answer is:

> ```
> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: "no such element: Unable to locate element:
> ```
>
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='Принять']"}
> (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)"

If i try to do it in browser - all is ok. Only one match.

Please help with it

Comment: if this span is inside a div tag, try clicking on the div tag instead. Xpath should be something like this //span[text() ='Принять']//ancestor::div[unique id here]

Comment: @itronic1990 it wasnt help. I tried: //button[./span[text()='Принять']] and other XPaths

Comment: I have HTML like `<!DOCTYPE>/body//iframe/#document/<!DOCTYPE>/body//span[text()='Принять']`                          I don't sure. It means i have doc inside another doc?

Comment: Please share the url or HTML.

Comment: there is an iframe, you should switch to the iframe, before clicking on the span

Answer (score 1):

Find the way! Thanks to @itronic1990 .

```
    Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
    var doc = (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement)_driver.ExecuteQuery(
        "return document");
    doc.FindElementByXPath("//button[./span[text()='Принять']]").Click();
```